# css inheriting styles from above

Tags: css, inheritance, styles

warning, this may require some really basic advice.

I am using a responsive stylesheet where styles for a mobile device are addressed first. as you progress down the stylesheet, you will find media queries for devices getting progressively larger (320 and up).
My question is, for every style I define for mobile (at the top), do I have to specify a counter-style if I don't want that style for my larger devices. Or is there a simple 'do not inherit'
eg. This is for mobile

```
          nav li {height:60px;}
```

For larger screens I don't want to specify a height at all.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple write:

```
nav li { height: auto }
```

There is no "do not inherit"...

Using something like modernizr you can use `.touch` or `.no-touch` classes on the `<html>` and many other useful for this scope as well.